# C# SQL -What is the best way to INSERT or SELECT text to or from a db table with line breaks

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am creating a footer of a receipt with `Graphic.DrawString`. The data is being `SELECT` from my database. Currently my table design holds 5 fields for the lines (line 1, 2, 3 up to 7). They are all single lines which is not very flexible. Say I want to put in a promo or a fairly long message on my footer. I am thinking of changing my table design to have 1 column of just the message and the data type probably `text` or `varchar`. What can I do to put multiple lines in that field?

EDIT: (Update: My receipt is created in Winform)

Comment: varchar will maintain carriage returns with no problem. Now if you want these lines breaks to show up in html you will have to get a little creative. Do NOT use the text datatype. It has been deprecated in favor of varchar(max) since sql 2005.

Comment: Use CRLF characters?

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal My program is in Winform (Updated my question). Thank you for the info about text data type though. Will I be able to maintain the line breaks and beginning spaces when I SELECT them in C#?

Comment: If you have spaces in the data you will have spaces in the strings in c#. Why not just try it? For displaying in a windows forms app you need to make sure that whatever control you are using for display supports multiple line presentation.

Comment: I will try it. @SeanLange what about when printing in paper? will it still display the line breaks?

Comment: You seem to be overly concerned with the kind of presentation that people do everyday. Of course spaces will be maintained. A line break is just a character like any other character. However, when being presented it inserts a line break instead of series of dark pixels like a "normal" character. Again, try it.

Comment: Thank you @SeanLange. Yes, I am a bit overly concerned about it.

Comment: The best way to find out if something will print a certain way is to stick a piece of paper in the printer and print it. :) You are going to have to do that anyway before you are done.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this code.

```
private string GetDBString(string SqlFieldName, SqlDataReader Reader)
    {
return Reader[SqlFieldName].Equals(DBNull.Value) ? String.Empty : Reader.GetString(SqlFieldName);
    }
```

Then try something like this.

```
private void somemethod()
{
string query = "SELECT * FROM [mssql_table_name] WHERE id=1";
//I suppose you should have your datarow as id one. This helps a lot or where line="data in that"
//whatever helps to find your row
SqlConnection sqc = new SqlConnection(connection_string); // Defined by you
sqc.Open();
SqlCommand command = SqlCommand(query,sqc);
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
this.footer.Text = GetDBString("line1", reader) + "\n" + GetDBString("line",reader)... etc;
```

All you need is before the new GetDBString insert between: + "\n " +

I hope I did help you and I understood your problem well.

Comment: You should use `Environment.NewLine` instead of `"\n"`.